# C言語の基本的なコードのバグ

Tags: c

C言語初心者です.以下はバグのあったコードです.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int repeat;

    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;

    int v;
    int add;
    char command[10];

    char str[3];
    scanf("%d", &repeat);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<repeat; i=i+1){
        scanf("%s %d %d",&command, &v, &add);
        if (command == "SET"){
            if (v == 1){
                value1 += add;
                printf("%s %d %d\n", command, value1, value2);
                //ここで,addが例えば,SET 1 10と入力するとadd==1となる.しかも,value1==-1となる.(value1+=addのはずが,逆に引き算される.)
            }
            else{
                printf("%d", v);
                value2 += add;
                printf("%s %d %d\n", command, value1, value2);
                //ここで,例えば,SET 2 20と入力するとvalue1にadd==2が引き算されてvalue1==-3になる.
            }
        }
        else if (command == "ADD"){
        ここから下は省略.
```

これらのバグが起きる原因が分かりません.
この一連のバグの原因はaddにあると思われるのですが,詳しく教えていただけないでしょうか?

Answer (score 3):

とりあえずchar [] の比較を==でしているのは気になる。
C言語ならstrcmpとかでは？

デバッガでちゃんと問題の箇所を実行しているか確認してみるのがいいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

```
char command[10];

scanf("%s %d %d",&command, &v, &add);
```

`scnaf`の`%s`が要求するのは文字列の先頭アドレスです。`&command`は先頭アドレスを格納した変数のアドレスとなっています。正しくは`command`です。

たいていのコンパイラーであれば、引数が正しく指定されていない旨を警告してくれるはずです。[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pgTYeDACVQ735wN0)

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:17:17: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]' [-Wformat=]
   17 |         scanf("%s %d %d",&command, &v, &add);
      |                ~^        ~~~~~~~~
      |                 |        |
      |                 char *   char (*)[10]
prog.c:18:21: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
   18 |         if (command == "SET"){
      |                     ^~
```

（Jogenaraさんの指摘されているように文字列比較もおかしいです。）

Comment: 先頭アドレスを格納した変数ってなんじゃろ？　`&command` は単純に配列全体へのポインタ右辺値っすよね。アドレス値は `command` と同じで型違いなだけで。

Comment: スタックに生配列とると同じアドレスになるんですかね。mallocとかで領域確保すると違いが出そう

Comment: 仕様はどうなってるんだろう。gccだと値は同じみたいですね 。https://wandbox.org/permlink/wn4Sjje1o2RdNsCB

Comment: あ、単に配列全体へのポインタですね 774RRが書いてた

Comment: jogenaraさん,sayuriさん,ありがとうございます.
C言語の==は配列においてはそのポインタが等しいかどうか調べているのですね!